# Finding and removing html tags with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

This is the code I am using:

```php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('index.html');
echo $html->find('tr', 15);
```

This will find the row 15 of the table. What I want to do is to remove that row completely.

I have already tried

```php
$html->find('tr', 15)=null;
```

But that does not seem to work. I have tried finding the info on the [SimpleHTMLDom documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) but it does no contain much information.

Answer (score 1):

simple_html_dom does not seems to allow the deletion.

Try with this instead:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTMLFile('index.html');
$element = $html->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(15);
$element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
```

Comment: the script stops responding after i use your code.is it possible to do so with phpquery or any other library

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the line `$html = new DOMDocument;` by `$html = new DOMDocument();`, and `load` by `loadHTMLFile`. This should works, I've used that method several times.

Comment: hello friend,this still not removing anything can you show me the working example if possible

Answer (score 0):

here you have a working example (works as is in Linux, but is easily adaptable).

File `dom_test.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTMLFile('index.html');
    $element = $html->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(1);
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);

    echo $html->saveHTML();
?>
```

Where the `index.html` contains:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td> hi </td><td>there</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td> HELLO </td>
                <td> there </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td> hi </td><td>there</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Put both files in the same directory and execute this in the console:

```
php dom_test.php
```

The output will appears without the "HELLO there" row.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple_html_dom, just set the outertext to the value of innertext

```
foreach($html->find('div') as $div) {
    $div->outertext = $div->innertext;
}
```